# FreeRTOS - Creating Project MinGW or MSVC, undefined reference to "xTaskCreate"

Tags: visual-c++, mingw, project, demo, freertos

I'm newbie with FreeRTOS and i'm trying to compile a simply example application.
If i open the demo application with Microsoft Visual Studio, it works greatly, but once i remove all .c leave only main.c with some simply instatements like xTaskCreate(), cause this errors:
undefined reference to: xTaskCreate();
I've tried also to create a new project with include all header, but the result it's the same.
Toolchain tried: Codeblock and Eclipse Luna with MinGW header and Microsoft Visual Studio with header MSVC
I've seen that in the source file, there aren't .lib or .dll but only .h.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Resolved, leaving all kernel .h .c files and then add a new main.c, Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

This was the solution posted on the [FreeRTOS support forum](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/freertos_support_forum_archive_index.html):

"Don't delete any files from the "FreeRTOS Source" directory in the MSVC 
project. They implement the FreeRTOS kernel, so without them your 
application will not link."